# Display first X elements obtained from a json if press a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm noob in Javascript and I want to make a button for load images, my idea is.. Get the Json data from an url and save it in a js array.. if the user press the button, show the ten first images, and if press again show the next ten images, this to the end..

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
    var a = [""];

    $.each(tumblr_api_read.posts, function(i, item) {
        a[i] += '<li><a href="' + item.url + '"><img src="' + item['photo-url-500'] + '" alt="' + item.slug + '"/></a></li>';
    });

    $(".portfolio-margin").on("click", ".read-more", function(){
        var i, b = "";

        for (i = 1; i < 10; ++i) {
            b += a[i];
        }
        $(".grid").append(b);
    });
});
```

The code is not finished, but the problem.. I don't know how load the next images, and the var "b" returns "undefined" in the beginning of each li: `undefined<li></li>undefined<li>..`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of

```
a[i] +=
```

is considered as

```
a[i] = a[i] + new value
//      ^ undefined initially
```

Initially, `a[i]` will always be undefined. So you are getting undefined.

Change that line to as I dont' see any reason to concatenate(`+=`). Iterator `i` will always occur once.

```
a[i] = '<li><a href="' + item.url + '"><img src="' + item['photo-url-500'] + '" alt="' + item.slug + '"/></a></li>';
//   ^ Here
```

Comment: @ShaunakD, its always that little detail that some forget ;)

Comment: Previously I didn't used an array on the each and I forgotten :c @ShaunakD You really helped me, I'm so stupid.. *facepalm*

Comment: Happens. Everyone has been through it . :D